# Python Bokeh CustomJS for Widgets

Tags: javascript, python, pandas, charts, bokeh

I have a pandas DataFrame similar to the one below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['item'], data=list(range(0,15)))
df['crit'] = ['crit1','crit2','crit3']*5
df['label'] = np.random.choice(['label1','label2','label3'], size=(15,1))
df.head()
```

[image]

I am plotting a Bar chart with Bokeh

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.charts import Bar
from bokeh.layouts import layout
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import CheckboxButtonGroup

source = ColumnDataSource(df)
p = Bar(df, label='label', values='item', agg='count', legend=None)
checkbox = CheckboxButtonGroup(labels=["Opt1", "Opt2", "Opt3"], active=[0, 1])
grid = layout([[p], [checkbox]])
show(grid)
```

[image]

I would like to add a custom JS callback that filters and sort the dataframe to update the plot. For example by clicking on the button 'Opt2' I would like to filter the dataframe to only keep rows where crit==crit2 and I would like the dataframe to be sorted (to have the bars in decreasing order).

I am not familiar with JS, only Python is my friend... Is it something easily achievable? Could someone put me in the track? The example I found on the bokeh documentation did not correspond to this use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this bokeh gallery example (IMDB movies):
https://demo.bokeh.org/movies

Its code is here:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/movies/main.py

Last part does exactly what you want, look into this function:

```
def select_movies():
```

Comment: Just to be pedantically clear about things, this is a python callback on the Bokeh server, not a `CustomJS` callback as mentioned in the question. But it's not possible to e.g., run pandas code in a `CustomJS` callback, so if using pandas is a requirement, the Bokeh server is required anyway.